# Breaking out of a loop when user inputs quit or exit c#

Tags: c#

I'm having trouble with looping my program so that it breaks out of the loop if user enters "quit" or "exit".

When I type any string, my program crashes as it tries to parse the string input to an int.  Any advice?

```
    namespace DiceRolling
    {
    /* We’re going to write a program that makes life easier for the player of a game like this. Start the
    program off by asking the player to type in a number of dice to roll.Create a new Random
    object and roll that number of dice.Add the total up and print the result to the user. (You should
    only need one Random object for this.) For bonus points, put the whole program in a loop and allow them to keep typing in numbers
    until they type “quit” or “exit”.  */

    class DiceRolling
    {
        static void RollDice(int numTries) 
        {
            Random random = new Random();

            //Console.Write("Please enter the number of dice you want to roll: ");
            //int numTries = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            int sum = 0;
            int dieRoll;

            for (int i = 1; i <= numTries; i++)
            {
                dieRoll = random.Next(6) + 1;
                Console.WriteLine(dieRoll);
                sum += dieRoll;
            }
            Console.WriteLine("The sum of your rolls equals: " + sum);
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            while (true)
            {
                Console.Write("Please enter the number of dice you want to roll: ");
                string input = Console.ReadLine();
                int numTries = Convert.ToInt32(input);
                //bool isValid = int.TryParse(input, out numTries);
                RollDice(numTries);
                Console.ReadKey();
                if (input == "quit" || input == "exit")
                    break;
            }
        } 
    }   
}
```

Comment: When parsing `"quit"` to int what do you expect to happen? Maybe you want some kind of menu where user enters a number instead which indicates "exit"? E.g. `0` or even `-1`?

Comment: Just move your check for quit or exit immediately after the readline of the variable input.

Comment: Also it's a tiny thing but the correct English term would be 'dice' not 'dices'.

Comment: Apologies for the pedantry, but you should know that the singular is "die" and the plural is "dice".  It's not "dices".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tigrams is pretty close, this is slightly better

```
Console.Write("Please enter the number of dices you want to roll: ");
string input = Console.ReadLine();
while (input != "quit" && input != "exit")
{
  int numTries = 0;
  if (int.tryParse(input, out numTries)
  {
    RollDice(numTries);
  }
  Console.Write("Please enter the number of dices you want to roll: ");
  input = Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    while (true)
    {
        Console.Write("Please enter the number of dices you want to roll: ");
        string input = Console.ReadLine();
        if (input == "quit" || input == "exit") //check it immediately here 
            break;

        int numTries = 0; 
        if(!int.TryParse(input, out numTries)) //handle not valid number
        {
           Console.WriteLine("Not a valid number");
           continue;
        }


        RollDice(numTries);
        Console.ReadKey();

    }
```

Comment: Thanks Tigran.  Question - if i input something other than an int, "quit" or "exit".  My program would still technically crash during the int numTries = Convert.ToInt32(input).  Any advice on how to fix this?

Comment: @KyleCheung: I updated answer with handling of non valid input. Where "non valid" means not  an `int` number.

Answer (score 1):

tried to make it as similar as possible to what you have

```
    while (true)
    {
        Console.Write("Please enter the number of dices you want to roll: ");
        string input = Console.ReadLine();
        int numTries;
        if (int.TryParse(input, out numTries))
        {
            RollDice(numTries);
        }
        else if(input == "quit" || input == "exit")
        {
            break;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `int numTries =int.Parse(input != null ? input: "0");`